# How to return a value through recursive call in Python

Tags: python, recursion, mergesort

I am trying a to solve a problem. There are a few programs where I have to return a value in variable throughout various function calls(Recursive calls). I am not sure how to do that.

I am trying Merge Sort algorithm in python this is the implementation:

```
def merge(arr,lo,hi):
    mid=(lo+hi)//2
    c=0
    i=lo; j=mid+1; k=0;
    temp=[]
    
    while(i<=mid and j<=hi):
        if arr[i]>arr[j]:
            temp.append(arr[j])
            c+=mid-i+1
            j+=1
            k+=1
        else:
            temp.append(arr[i])
            i+=1
            k+=1
            
    while(i<=mid):
        temp.append(arr[i])
        i+=1
        k+=1
    while(j<=hi):
        temp.append(arr[j])
        j+=1
        k+=1
    for i in range(k):
        arr[lo+i]=temp[i]
    return c
def mergeSort(arr,lo,hi):
    if lo==hi:
        return
    mid=(lo+hi)//2
    mergeSort(arr,lo,mid)
    mergeSort(arr,mid+1,hi)
    merge(arr,lo,hi)
```

In addition to merge sort I am counting the number of elements which are smaller than a particular element(not much Important). For which I am using a count variable 'c'.
**Now I have to return the C value through all the recursive calls and back to my main function. I am not sure how to do that. Someone help me to return it.**
I also tried returning like this:
return mergeSort(arr,lo,mid)

But It just returns 0.
My main function gives the call to mergeSort(arr,0,n-1)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: While it's not clear what `c` is counting, you have to accumulate the value returned by each recursive call into the local `c`, like you do with the return value of `merge`. *Then* you can return `c`.

Comment: It's also unclear why `merge` is calculating a mid-point at all. Merging is a straight linear process of turning two sorted lists into a single sorted lists. It's only `mergesort` that cares about splitting an *unsorted* list in half.

Comment: I just want to know how to return c to the main function. yes merge doesn't need mid, but since I have only one Array I am dividing it into two(not actually), then sorting them

Comment: how do I accumulate the value returned by each recursive call

Comment: The same way you did with `merge`: `c += mergesort(...)`.

Comment: but the function that is returning the c value is the merge function, does it work, c+=mergesort() since mergesort() doesn't return any value

Comment: Even If I perform c+=... in my mergeSort() function I have to initialize it somewhere to 0. then pass to to all the function calls and at last return the accumulated value

Comment: That's fine. The `c` you initialize in one call is *independent* of the `c` you initialize in a different call. Same name, different variables, because they are allocated in a different call frame.

Comment: Your original code was passing `c` as an argument and returning it in the base case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is add up the values returned by each recursive call and by `merge`, then return that value.

```
def mergeSort(arr,lo,hi):
    if lo==hi:
        return 0
    c = 0
    mid=(lo+hi)//2
    c += mergeSort(arr,lo,mid)
    c += mergeSort(arr,mid+1,hi)
    c += merge(arr,lo,hi)
    return c
```